# Org mode shell blocks output with "raw" and "replace"

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

In Org Babel, in a bash code block, it seems impossible to get both `:results` header arg with both `raw` and `replace`. Is that expected?

The [docs](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-shell.html) for shell Babel seem to suggest the only options for `:results` are `file`, `list`, and `table`. It seems weird that there is no way to just show the string sent to stdout by the shell code.

`raw` seems to work as an argument, but it makes `replace` not work. For instance in

```
#+begin_src bash :results raw replace
  tree .
#+end_src
```

where both `list` and `table` garble the result.

Comment: While I was testing, I found that just `:results output` seems to do the job. The docs mention that `output` is the default, however that info seems wrong, as it looks like `output list` is the actual default .

Comment: Anything except `raw` does the job, in the sense that `replace` (which *is* the default) can figure out where the results end so that they can be cleared before the new results are inserted. `raw` just does not provide any markers to allow `replace` to do that. I've recommended `drawer` in the past instead of `raw`. @dalanicolai: `output` is a different kettle of fish - it's independent of the format (I can have `:results output raw` or `:results output drawer` e.g.); what it contrasts with is `:results value`. `output` is the default for many languages but not all (e.g. for `elisp` ...)

Comment: ... (e.g. for `elisp` the default is `value` - in fact there are various claims that `value` is the default for most languages, but I prefer to set it explicitly when I don't know for sure). Most of these things are described in [Results of Evaluation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html) but the default value for the `Collection` has to be dug up from the specific language doc (or maybe its implementation - not every language is documented).

Comment: @NickD I am largely aware of most points you mention here, but indeed I did not really think about how things should behave (the 'solution' simply worked). The situation is that for bash blocks, the output often automatically gets formatted as a list, like for the `tree .` output (I realize now, that this is just 'normal' org behavior, also without the `list` output value). For some reason, `:results output` prevents the output from getting formatted as a list. I now realize that this should not make a difference (AFAIK) but it does, as it makes the output to get wrapped as an example block.

Comment: `as it makes the output to get wrapped as an example block` : that is standard behavior for output that is longer than 10 lines (configurable through `org-babel-min-lines-for-block-output`). Try `tree . | sed 5q`.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I did not know about the 10 lines 'rule' and the `org-babel-min-lines-for-block-output`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `drawer` instead of `raw`:

```
#+begin_src shell :results drawer replace
tree .
#+end_src
```

`raw` does not provide any markers, so `replace` cannot figure out where the results end: you just get the new results prepended to the old results.
`drawer` encloses the raw results in a drawer, enabling `replace` to figure out where the results end, so it can clear the old results before inserting the new ones.